# How do I create an exponentially recurrent item in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

What I am trying to do is essentially this:

1. First, a TODO item should pop up in my agenda after a one day (/week)
2. Second, a TODO item should pop up in 2 days after that
3. ... in 3 days after that...

and later according to the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: What's exponential about what you describe?

Comment: Well, the Fibonacci sequence does grow exponentially. Asymptotically, $F_n = O(\phi^n)$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio ($\phi = 1.61...$).  I don't think there is a way to specify that in Org mode, and why would you? In roughly 30 iterations, you'd be way beyond human lifetimes (and certainly way beyond computer lifetimes).

Comment: Actually, you *might* be able to use so-called `diary sexps` to do the calculation. See [Timestamps](https://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html#Timestamps) in the Org manual and [Sexp Diary Entries](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sexp-Diary-Entries.html) in the Emacs manual.

Comment: @nickD it's about developing a habit but not regular. Essentially, I want to have a calendar of revising old leetcode problems

Comment: @NickD I don't understand how it would help me to make it show up in the agenda.